# 2D Graphics and uniform scaling in HTML Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, 2d, scaling

I've got a camera object that "zooms" into the canvas by scaling up the context by a fixed and constant variable. This is an example:

```
zoom: function(zoomConstant) {
    this.scaleFactor = this.scaleFactor + zoomConstant;
}

update: function(context) {
    context.scale(this.scaleFactor, this.scaleFactor);
}
```

It works fine until reaching really high scale values, where the zooming transition is no longer smooth and scrolling in and out with the mouse wheel becomes unbearably slow.

I'm looking for a cubic scaling function that would scale less at higher scale values, giving a visually uniform transition. Unfortunately, I'm not great with the terminology and I'm not sure what to look up. It would be great if you could suggest any sources that I could research, and perhaps give an example of how it would work with the Canvas.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a linear function to zoom. A linear function only changes the zoom amount by say 1, so to scale from 100 to 10 takes 90 steps, but from 10 to 1 only 9, however the magnification is 10x in both cases. You could try scaling by say 10percent of scaleFactor:

```
this.scaleFactor*=0.9;
```

So if your magnification was 100, you would go to 90, then 81, etc... But I would also set a minimum step size, or offer greater control over zooming (rapid vs. precise).

Answer (score 0):

You don't show much code :-/

**So at least 2 possibilities come to mind:**

- The user is spinning the mousewheel too quickly for the canvas to redraw all the requested draws. If this is the case you'll want to throttle the mousewheel events with a technique called "debouncing". Google: debounce events
- If you're forcing the canvas to redraw the entire original image at increasing size, then canvas is being slowed because it must calculate every pixel outside the canvas so that it knows which pixels to draw inside the canvas. You can fix this by using the clipping version of `context.drawImage` to select a smaller piece of the original image & scale that smaller piece instead of the whole image.

Answer (score 0):

If you use accumulative scaling, as in this case, the higher end will logarithmically scale, creating large steps.

You probably want to use an absolute scale factor, so if you change this line:

```
update: function(context) {
    context.scale(this.scaleFactor, this.scaleFactor);
}
```

to

```
update: function(context) {
    context.setTransform(this.scaleFactor, 0, 0, this.scaleFactor, 0, 0);
}
```

The scale will be using an absolute approach (if you need other transforms you need to set them here as well as this method overrides all transforms).

Illustration:

First line is accumulative, second absolute. There is more fine grain control with the second. You can also use two different step factors one for when scaleFactor < 1 and one for => 1.

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    scaleFactor = 1,
    step = 1.1,  // 10%
    i = 0,
    dx = 1;

ctx.translate(-100,0);

// accumulative
for(; i < 20; i++) {
  ctx.fillRect(100, 20, 5, 10);
  scaleFactor *= step;
  ctx.scale(scaleFactor, 1);
}

// absolute
ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, -100, 0);
scaleFactor = 1;
for(i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  ctx.fillRect(100, 50, 5, 10);
  scaleFactor *= step;
  ctx.setTransform(scaleFactor, 0, 0, 1, -100, 0);
}
```

```css
canvas {border:1px solid #000}
```

```html
<canvas width=500></canvas>
```